# How to use log4j2.component.properties file for org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Clock

Tags: java, log4j2, properties-file

According to this [log4j2 configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html) I am trying to set the "log4j2.component.properties" file in my NetBeans project. I have already configured my log4j2 with ASYNC_LOGGERS and one thing I particularly need is the "log4j.Clock" property. Because I get the data at a very high speed from the Servers and we expect that the logging timestamp needs to be perfect. 
How can I use the "log4j2.component.properties" file in my project. Currently I created the "log4j2.component.properties" file in my default package of the project and set the values as below:

**My log4j2.component.properties file**

```
Log4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
AsyncLogger.RingBufferSize=512*1024
-DAsyncLoggerConfig.RingBufferSize=512*1024
log4j.Clock=SystemClock
```

**My log4j2.xml file**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
  <Appenders>
     <RollingRandomAccessFile name="Messages-log" fileName="Log4J/Messages-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
               immediateflush="true" filePattern="Log4J/Messages-%d{MM-dd-yyyy-HH}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>

    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="Error-log" fileName="Log4J/Errors-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
               immediateflush="false" filePattern="Log4J/Errors-%d{MM-dd-yyyy-HH}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>

  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="Messages-log" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Messages-log" level="info"/>
      </Logger>
    <Logger name="Error-log" level="info" additivity="false">       
        <appender-ref ref="Error-log" level="info"/>
    </Logger>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Messages-log"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Error-log"/>
    </root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Is this correct way of using it? I am highly confused in how to use it. I want the timestamp to be perfect and so I want to use the "log4j2.clock" parameter set to "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Clock". All I want is asynchronous logging with the exact time when the record has reached. But I am getting the following exception:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Could not create org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Clock: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Clock, using default SystemClock for timestamps.
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: log4j2.component.properties is just one .properties file which forms part of a hierarchy of possible configuration sources.

See: [Log4J2 Configuration - System Properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties) for an explanation of how this works.

Comment: The page mentioned is not available anymore. Check this for more examples. https://dzone.com/articles/log4j-2-configuration-using-properties-file or https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html